# Best way to store last-touched time in Cassandra

Tags: database, postgresql, cassandra

I'm storing a last-touched time in a User table in Postgres, but there are many frequent updates and enough contention that I can see examples of 3 of the same updates deadlocking.

Cassandra seems a better fit for this - but should I devote a table to just this purpose? And I don't need old timestamps, just the latest. Should I use something other than Cassandra?
If I should use Cassandra, any tips on table properties?

The table I have in mind:

```
CREATE TABLE ksp1.user_last_job_activities (
    user_id bigint,
    touched_at timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, touched_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (touched_at DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

**Update**

Thanks! I did some experiments around writetime and since I had to write a value anyway, I just wrote the time.

Like so:

```
CREATE TABLE simple_user_last_activity (
    user_id bigint,
    touched_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO simple_user_last_activity (user_id, touched_at) VALUES (6, dateof(now()));
SELECT touched_at from simple_user_last_activity WHERE user_id = 6;
```

Since touched_at is no longer in the primary key, only one record per user is stored.

**Update 2**

There's another option that I am going to go with. I can store the job_id too, which gives more data for analytics:

```
CREATE TABLE final_user_last_job_activities (
    user_id bigint,
    touched_at timestamp,
    job_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, touched_at)
) 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (touched_at DESC)
AND default_time_to_live = 604800;
```

Adding the 1-week TTL takes care of expiring records - if there are none I return current time.

```
INSERT INTO final_user_last_job_activities (user_id, touched_at, job_id) VALUES (5, dateof(now()), 5);
INSERT INTO final_user_last_job_activities (user_id, touched_at, job_id) VALUES (5, dateof(now()), 6);
INSERT INTO final_user_last_job_activities (user_id, touched_at, job_id) VALUES (5, dateof(now()), 7);
INSERT INTO final_user_last_job_activities (user_id, touched_at, job_id) VALUES (5, dateof(now()), 6);

SELECT * FROM final_user_last_job_activities LIMIT 1;
```

Which gives me:

```
 user_id | touched_at               | job_id
---------+--------------------------+--------
       5 | 2015-06-17 12:43:30+1200 |      6
```

Simple benchmarks show no significant performance difference in storing or reading from the bigger table.

Comment: Cassandra has implicit support for `writetime` per each column. See [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_writetime.html), looks like that is what you are looking for here.

Comment: @MSD `writetime` is far from perfect. It doesn't work on any collection type, it doesn't work on primary key. And of course it cannot be used to see when a cell has been deleted. In a way it certainly isn't an audit log. But in SQL datastores, it is a common practice to have two dates the `creation_date` and the `modification_date`, I start to believe this might be a good practice for cassandra as well.

Answer (score 4):

Because c* is last write wins, you can simply keep the latest versions of each row.

You could, as MSD suggests, use `writetime` to pull the time of the write. But be careful because this is column specific and you can't use write time on your primary key columns. For example in a table as follows:

```
cqlsh> create TABLE test.test ( a int, b int, c int, d int, primary key (a))
   ... ;
cqlsh> insert INTO  test.test (a, b, c, d) VALUES ( 1,2,3,4)
   ... ;

cqlsh> select * from test.test
   ... ;

 a | b    | c | d
---+------+---+------
 1 |    2 | 3 |    4

(2 rows)

cqlsh> insert into test.test (a,c) values (1, 6);
cqlsh> select * from test.test ;

 a | b    | c | d
---+------+---+------
 1 |    2 | 6 |    4

(2 rows)
cqlsh> select writetime(a), writetime(b), writetime(c), writetime(d) from test.test
   ... ;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot use selection function writeTime on PRIMARY KEY part a"

cqlsh> select  writetime(b), writetime(c), writetime(d) from test.test  ;

 writetime(b)     | writetime(c)     | writetime(d)
------------------+------------------+------------------
 1434424690700887 | 1434424690700887 | 1434424702420929
```

Otherwise you can add a cql column with the timestamp:

```
create TABLE test.test ( a int, b int, c int, d int, touched_at timeuuid, primary key (a)) ;
```

Some quick benchmarking would help you determine which is more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra has implicit support for `writetime` per each column. See [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_writetime.html), looks like that is what you are looking for here.