# Cassandra row creation timestamp

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

The `writetime` function returns the creation timestamp associated with a non-PK column.

I need an equivalent for PK columns, in order to determine the creation timestamp of a partition/row.

The data seems to be internally available: LivenessInfo can be seen through `sstabledump`.

Is there a way to access a row's liveness info from CQL?

Answer (score 1):

These things may clarify your doubt upto some extent

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_writetime.html

You can just create a extra column for storing the timestamp
[Best way to store last-touched time in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855412/best-way-to-store-last-touched-time-in-cassandra)

Comment: Sorry but that is not an answer to my question. I'm looking for a way to access the first-touched time of a row (AKA partition), not the last-touched time for a field.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use writeTime on PRIMARY KEY part**

As far as i know there is no way, you have to manually create another field and store the time whenever a new primary key inserted.

Comment: That would require using IF NOT EXISTS in my INSERT statement, which I would prefer to avoid

Answer (score 0):

The pre 3.0 sstable storage format doesn't have this information so it would be impossible to support until the previous format is completely deprecated.

Comment: Why not support a new, and reasonable, functionality from version 3.0 onward? I don't understand your logic.

Comment: The coordinator cannot tell what format the replicas sstables are in. And there can be mixed, so it currently cant tell if it can satisfy the query or not. Because it wasnt possible before its really just a matter of no one has thought or written code to to support it yet.  You can open a jira at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/summary and someone may take it up or you can submit patch yourself.